# RestEasy / CDI on TomEE 1.5.2

Tags: cdi, resteasy, apache-tomee

I'm trying to get a ResteasyApplication running. My major problem is to implement CDI which should be not too hard.

So here is my prob. I'm using `@Named` on my `Service` class and `@Inject` at my `RestService` class

```cs
@Path("/patient")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON 

}) 
@Consumes    
@Stateless
public class PatientREST {


    @Inject
    PatientService patientService;...
```

---

```cs
@Named
public class PatientService {

    // Resteasy demands a no-arg constructor
    public PatientService() {
    }


    public Patient getPatient(String patientNumber) {...
```

My beans.xml looks like this

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

All over I tried to use it like several TomEE- HowTos describes.

When I'm trying to deploy this on my TomEE (1.5.2) I'm getting this in the stacktrace.

```
uses @Inject but CDI is not enabled. Maybe youd need to add a beans.xml file.


javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [de.klinikum.service.PatientService] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  patientService, Bean Owner : [PatientREST, Name:null, WebBeans Type:ENTERPRISE, API Types:[java.lang.Object,de.klinikum.communication.PatientREST,java.io.Serializable], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
```

Any Idea?

I was trying a bit more .. and now... deployment works. But I still get an HTTP500 Failure caused by an null pointer

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    de.klinikum.communication.PatientREST.getPatient(PatientREST.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.37 logs.
```

Seems like the container is not able to provide the patientService bean... but why ?

.------------------
Still get the same Failure.. Maybe I need some special dependencys ? ...
Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.klinikumlmu.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>KlinikumServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>KlinikumServer</name>
    <properties>
        <sesame.version>
            2.7.0
        </sesame.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeVersion>1.5.2</tomeeVersion>
                    <!-- <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0-4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${sesame.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-tomee</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

I'm geeting deeper an deeper into it. 
I've tried to place the beans.xml in the WEB-INF Folder and in the META-INF Folder to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we got the answer^^..

to use CDI with Resteasy and TomEE you have to include special resteasy cdi dependency. Since we use this everything works find...

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for our help...

Answer (score 0):

Your REST end point needs to have `@RequestScoped` on it to enable CDI injection.  Also, your injection point should be

`@Inject
@Named("PatientService")
    PatientService patientService;`

Since you have a `@Named` on the service.

An aside, there is no such thing as TomEE 7.  There is TomEE 1.5.x and Tomcat 7.0.  I'm assuming you're using TomEE 1.5.x

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference about the `@Named` qualifier, it isn't treated as a real qualifier anyway by Weld (not sure about OWB).

Comment: I tried it but there is still the NullPoint Failure.. Really can not say what my problem is.. Are there any special dependencys which I need to use in my pom ? I've posted my pom file above..

Comment: I guess I jumped the gun a little.  Are you deploying to TomEE or Tomcat 7?

Comment: I wonder if maybe you have to do something like this: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasy-CDIIntegration since you're not using the container's provided JAX-RS implementation.